# knitr. Splitting a function into several blocks

Tags: r, knitr

Is it possible with knitr to split an R function across several blocks (for documentation reasons)? Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Part1 gives salutation. 
<<part1>>=
hello <- function(x){
  print("Hi")
@
Part2 adds the name.
<<part2>>=
  print(x)}
@
\end{document}
```

Comment: You could just set the `chunk` option `eval` to `FALSE`? Another possibility would be to use the `listings` package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a `chunk` option called `eval`, which controls whether or not the code is actually evaluated by R. If you set it to `FALSE`, then the code will not be evaluated, and so you could, in principle, type whatever you wanted to type.

Additionally, as [Yihui points out in the comments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/176100/knitr-splitting-a-function-into-several-blocks#comment408091_176171), you can use `<<part3, ref.label=c('part1', 'part2')>>=` to combine your `part1` and `part2` and actually evaluate the code.

In the following MWE, I've added such a `part3`, setting `echo` to `FALSE`, so that nothing appears, as you already have the code displayed in parts 1 and 2. Then, if you'd like, you can add a `part4` where you actually pass an argument to the function that you've defined.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

Part1 gives salutation. 
<<part1, eval=FALSE>>=
hello <- function(x){
  print("Hi")
@
Part2 adds the name.
<<part2, eval=FALSE>>=
  print(x)}
@

<<part3, ref.label=c('part1', 'part2'), echo=FALSE>>=
@

<<part4>>=
hello("Dan Wright")
@

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Using echo=FALSE,eval=TRUE with the function block and then just putting the code bits in LaTeX is what I have done before, but it seems against the ethos of knitr since you are not actually running those lines.

Comment: @DanWright You can combine the two chunks into a third chunk, then evaluate it, e.g. `<<part3, ref.label=c('part1', 'part2')>>>=`

Answer (score 3):

[Read up on the chunk options available](http://yihui.name/knitr/options) and [see how to use them](https://github.com/yihui/knitr-examples).

In this paricular case, the `echo` *and* `eval` options can be used together...

```
<<the_func, echo=FALSE>>=
hello <- function(x){
  print("Thanks")
  print(x)
}
@

<<the_func, echo=1:2, eval=FALSE>>=
@

<<the_func, echo=3:4, eval=FALSE>>=
@
```

Answer (score 0):

The ref.label option solves this. Here is the working example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Part1 gives salutation. 
<<part1,eval=FALSE>>=
hello <- function(x){
  print("Thanks")
@
Part2 adds the name.
<<part2,eval=FALSE>>=
  print(x)}
@
<<part3,echo=FALSE,ref.label=c('part1','part2')>>=
@
<<executefunction>>=
hello('Adam and Yihue')
@
\end{document}
```